# Appending news and Date in the News API in Python

Tags: python

I am a new python developer. I have been trying to put date beside news in such a way that the title and the date will be beside each other but I keep getting error. When I remove the date, it works fine but when I try to put the date, it shows errors.

Below is the code with date:

```
    # fetching data in json format
    open_news = requests.get(main_url).json()

    # getting all articles in a string article
    article = open_news["articles"]

    # empty list which will
    # contain all trending news
    results = []

    for ar, dt in article:
        results.append(ar["title"], dt["publishedAt"]) 

    for i in range(len(results)):

        # printing all trending news
        print(i + 1, results[i])

# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # function call
    nigeriaNews()
```

I believe the error is coming from here: `results.append(ar["title"], dt["publishedAt"])` 
When I try to get the headlines like this, for ar in article:
`results.append(ar["title"])` It works fine. The same thing is applicable to date. But to get both of them at the same time has been an issue.

I just want to have the headlines and the dates beside each other like:
headline1 ------ date
headline2 ------ date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experience is that you're trying to add more than 1 item to an array row. To get around this you could add json e.g: `results.append({ "title": ar["title"], "publishedAt": dt["publishedAt"]})`. Although a more cleaner way will be to store your data in a model, either as a class or a named tuple.

Also when you get the data you should always check for 4xx and 5xx errors from the third party server using `raise_for_status()`.

For illustration purposes, below is how you can use named tuples:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Article = namedtuple('Article', ['title', 'publishedAt']) # Model to store the article.

def FormatArticle(articleJson):
    return Article(articleJson['title'], articleJson["publishedAt"])

# fetching data in json format
response = requests.get(main_url)
# You could log the response.text() and response.status_code()
response.raise_for_status() # This will throw an exception if status is 4xx or 5xx

open_news = response.json()
results = [FormatArticle(article) for article in open_news["articles"]]

#print(results) # You might also be able to do print([x._asdict() for x in results])
for x in results:
     print(f'title: {x.title} - published at: {x.publishedAt}')

# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # function call
    nigeriaNews()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `append` method only takes a single item and appends it to your list. Here are two ways that I think accomplish what you want:

Method 1:

```
for ar, dt in article:
    results.append(' ------ '.join(ar["title"], dt["publishedAt"])) 

for i in range(len(results)):
    # printing all trending news
    print(i + 1, results[i])
```

This will join together the title and date into a single string and then append that string to your list.

Method 2:

```
for ar, dt in article:
    results.append((ar["title"], dt["publishedAt"]))

for i in range(len(results)):
    # printing all trending news
    print(i + 1, results[i][0], '-----', results[i][1])
```

This will append a tuple of the title and date to your list and then the print function will separate the two elements of the tuple and print the separator string with it.

Answer (score 0):

The append() method adds a single item to the end of the list.
syntax: list.append(item) [Python List append()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append)
item can be numbers, strings, dictionaries, another list, and so on.

```
results = []
for ar, dt in article:
    results.append([ar["title"]], dt["publishedAt"]]) # adding list item in to results. 
for index, data in enumerate(results):                # enumerate returns index and data from a sequence.
    print(index+1, data[0], '------', data[1])        # print every article title, publish date with index.
```

to know more about enumerate refer this [Python enumerate()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Okay thanks for advising.  i have added comments , links and text as much as possible. i hope this will be more valuable.